# Maven fails building CAS server

Tags: maven, cas, jasig

I am trying to implement SSO feature and downloaded all projects and pom.xml from http://www.jasig.org/cas/download.

So, I got my maven project and then In eclipse I just did import as existing maven project.

then I Run the project as MVN CLEAN and it is not running and getting error as

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://developer.ja-sig.org/maven2/org/jasig/parent/jasig-parent/21/jasig-parent-21.pom
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/jasig/parent/jasig-parent/21/jasig-parent-21.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jasig/parent/jasig-parent/21/jasig-parent-21.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.jasig.cas:cas-server:3.5.0 (D:\CAS\Single Sign On\cas-server-3.5.0-release\cas-server-3.5.0\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact org.jasig.parent:jasig-parent:pom:21 from/to jasig-repository (http://developer.ja-sig.org/maven2): null to http://developer.ja-sig.org/maven2/org/jasig/parent/jasig-parent/21/jasig-parent-21.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 11: UnresolvedAddressException -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

some one told that it is proxy problem, so i changed settings.xml file to place proxy as

```
<proxy>
  <id>123</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>abc.def@xyz.com</username>
  <password>xyz1233</password>
  <host>proxy.com</host>
  <port>80</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>google.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

still it is not running, can someone please pointout mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Why not downloading jasig-parent from Maven central instead ?